# In Swift 3.1, UnsafeMutablePointer.initialize(from:) is deprecated

Tags: swift, unsafemutablepointer

In Swift 3.1, UnsafeMutablePointer.initialize(from:) is deprecated. Xcode suggests I use UnsafeMutableBufferPointer.initialize(from:) instead. I have a code block that looks like this:

```
let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 64)
pointer.initialize(from: repeatElement(0, count: 64))
```

The code gives me a compile time warning because of the deprecation. So I'm going to change that to:

```
let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 64)
let buffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: pointer, count: 64)
_ = buffer.initialize(from: repeatElement(0, count: 64))
```

Is this the right way to do this? I just wanted to make sure that I'm doing it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct, but you can allocate and initialize memory slightly simpler with

```
let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 64)
pointer.initialize(to: 0, count: 64)
```

Creating a *buffer* pointer view can still be useful because that
is a collection, has a `count` property and can be enumerated:

```
let buffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: pointer, count: 64)

for byte in buffer {
    // ...
}
```

but that is independent of how the memory is initialized.

Comment: Did not answer the question…

Comment: @StackUnderflow: The question was *"Is this the right way to do this"* which I answered with *"It is correct"* – followed by a simpler solution. Please let me know what you find unclear about this.

Comment: Compile time warning still exists.

Comment: @StackUnderflow: That is strange. I just double-checked with both Xcode 9.2 (Swift 4) and Xcode 9.3 beta 3 (Swift 4.1) that the above code compiles without warnings. – What exact warning do you get at which line?