# Preparing for Swift 4 - UnsafeMutablePointer migration to UnsafeMutableBufferPointer

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers, unsafemutablepointer

I've got a char-by-char function that returns a character from a file. It is pretty performant, as far as i now.

Xcode says that the `characterPointer.initialize(from: s.characters)` "will be removed in Swift 4.0." And I have to "use 'UnsafeMutableBufferPointer.initialize(from:)' instead".

But I can't get it. Can you please explain it to me. How to use a quick iterator over characters with a UnsafeMutableBufferPointer? Do you have an example?

This is my function:

```
/// Return next character, or nil on EOF.
func nextChar() -> Character? {
    //precondition(fileHandle != nil, "Attempt to read from closed file")

    if atEof {
        return nil
    }

    if stored_cnt > (stored_idx + 1) {
        stored_idx += 1
        let char = characterPointer.pointee
        characterPointer = characterPointer.successor()
        return char
    }

    let tmpData = fileHandle.readData(ofLength: (chunkSize))
    if tmpData.count == 0 {
        atEof = true
        return nil
    }

    if var s = NSString(data: tmpData, encoding: encoding.rawValue) as String! {
        characterPointer.initialize(from: s.characters)

        stored_idx = 0
        stored_cnt = s.characters.count
    }
    let char = characterPointer.pointee
    characterPointer = characterPointer.successor()
    return char
}
```

By the way, if there is a faster solution, please do not hesitate to tell me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you provide definitions for some of your undefined terms? For example, what _is_ `characterPointer`?

Comment: Sure. CharacterPointer is a UnsafeMutablePointer<Character>.allocate(capacity: 512

Comment: Ooooh, I found a discussion of what's going on here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0147-move-unsafe-initialize-from.md

Comment: Recently a [good thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43709407/6541007) describing the similar issue was added to SO. But your code has many critical flaws and I recommend you not to use it in actual apps. It may cause memory leak, destroy and access outside of the allocated region which may crash your app.

Comment: Thanks Matt, OOPer. Do you have a **save** solution of how to read a file char by char correctly and fast. OOPer mentioned critical flaws.

Comment: @PeterShaw: You could also directly read from `s.characters`, instead of copying it to allocated memory. – But there is another problem in your code: You might read a chunk ending with an incomplete UTF-8 sequence, and then the conversion to `(NS)String` fails.

Comment: Other two flaws. **_1_** Your code does not reset the `characterPointer` to the original position, (`initialize()` does not modify the pointer itself) so, it may destroy outside of the `allocate`d region when the read file contains more characters than the allocated size. **_2_** Your code does not have `deinitialize`. Once `initialize`d region needs to be `deinitialize`d before deallocating or re-using. This may not be a critical issue, when working with primitive types, but `Character` is not a simple primitive type, so follow the `allocate`-`initialize`-`deinitialize`-`deallocate` sequence.

Comment: And as Martin R noted, splitting a text file into fixed size chunks may cause problems for encodings which may encode a single character into multiple bytes like .utf8 or encodings which depends on the `state` of decoding like .iso2022JP . You may need to restrict your code to single-byte-only encodings (.ascii or .isoLatin1, etc), or else, read whole text file and then read characters one by one.

Comment: Thank you very much. I learned a lot. Will rewrite it tomorrow. Thanks for the explanation.